# How to stop Apache Server from command line

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm trying to stop Apache server from command line.

I'm using this command (admin) from the installation folder : `httpd -k stop`.

But I'm getting this error : `(OS 5)Access is denied.  : AH10014: Failed to open the 'Apache2.4' service`

What is this error? What permissions should I give?

Operating System : Windows 10 Pro

Command prompt is running with admin privileges.

Comment: Hey Saiteja. Welcome to Super User. It would help us help you if you could provide more information about your particular circumstance. What operating system are you using? Are you running the comand with root (for linux/bsd) or Administrator (windows) privileges? Please edit your question to include this information so others with see it.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong I've added the details you asked for.